# ASP.NET: Creating multiple printable pages and print them with one click

Tags: asp.net, printing

I want to achieve the following: create a number of instances of the same web page, each of the the pages displaying slighty different data (like customer name, address, ...). These pages should be printable with as less effort for the user as possible. The problem is that if you call the javascript print-directive on every page, the user would get a ton of the PrintDialogs. 
One solution to solve this problem would be to create those print pages dynamically during runtime and put them all on one page, separated by page breaks (so the user would only have to confirm the print dialog once). This solution has the huge problem that I can't use the Visual Studio designer to put my page together.
Another possible solution would be to build the template of the page in the designer, dynamically fill in the customer-specific data into the corresponding controls for every page, and then somehow chain all the resulting pages together to one long page; again separated by page breaks. But I dont really know how to do that....I tried to use the Render() event, get the HTMl code and then duplicate it, but I didnt have much success with it.

So, any guidance for the Render() approach or any other solutions would be very welcome!

Comment: Could you use SSRS to generate a report rather than one page you need to print out multiple times?

Comment: Hm I dont think so; the page I want to print is for the end-customer and contains graphics and some formatting. From what I can see, SSRS was not really made for that (and I'm not using SQL to access my data).

Comment: Actually, that's something SSRS (Reporting Services) is quite good at.  You can render the report, graphics, charts, formatted data and all, as a PDF, and stream it directly to the user.  But it does require tabular data, that's quite true.

Comment: I'll have another look at SSRS. I think if sub-tables and page breaks are possible, this should be a sufficient way to solve my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your data in any form of list?  Can it be put into one?  Not necessarily all of it, but an ID per desired page, or something similar?  Sufficiently that it could drive a data-bound control?

You could use a `Repeater` control on your page to build out your "pages" according to a template.  Page breaks could be achieved with CSS styles.  Then you'd have just one (long) page you had to print.

You could even make your "page" a `UserControl` to make data-driven variations in rendering easier to organize.

Comment: Yes, the data can be put in a list.
This might also be a solution because repeater seems to be able to use controls. I'll give it a try.